# How to detect unicode character range in Python?

Tags: python, unicode

I have a corpus of text documents that contain text in more than one language.

For each line I read, I have to find out which language it is written in. This is limited to three languages, viz, English, Hindi (U+0900–U+097F) and Telugu (U+0C00–U+0C7F).

How can I make my program filter the lines with different script?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `max()` to pick out the highest codepoint used, then match that against your ranges:

```
def detect_language(line):
    maxchar = max(line)
    if u'\u0c00' <= maxchar <= u'\u0c7f':
        return 'telugu'
    elif u'\u0900' <= maxchar <= u'\u097f':
        return 'hindi'
    return 'english'
```

Demo:

```
>>> detect_language(u'Hello world!')
'english'
>>> detect_language(u'తెలుు')
'telugu'
>>> detect_language(u'हिन्दी')
'hindi'
```

Comment: Hi @Martijin Why are you considering only max character? Please throw some light on it.

Comment: @RajanChauhan: If you know the highest codepoint is not in the Telugu range, there is no point in testing any of the other codepoints either, there won't be any other Telugu codepoints in the text. If that maximum codepoint is not found in the Hindi range either, then again none of the other codepoints won't either. Note that 'english' codepoints such as spaces and newlines are also used in Telugu and Hindi, so looking at other codepoints (not the maximum) could lead to false positives.